# Importing CSS in Semantic-UI-React

Tags: reactjs, redux, semantic-ui, create-react-app, semantic-ui-react

I will be using Semantic-UI-React in my project but I came across following issues:

Docs link : https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css

1. Docs say webpack 1 is supported but not recommended. I am using Create React App which comes with webpack version 1.14.0. So does that mean I should not use `Semantic-UI-React` with CRA?
2. For styling, I also want some custom styles in my project , so I went with third option of `Semantic UI` package mentioned in the docs..
   `npm install semantic-ui --save-dev` runs `gulp` internally and creates a `semantic` folder. But there is no `dist` folder as mentioned in the docs. From which path I should refer the `semantic.min.css` in my index.js file?

I am basically trying to use `Semantic-UI-React` with `semantic.min.css` with some of my own styles on top of it. But it seems I am making some mistake in the setup. Another option may be to go ahead with `Semantic UI CSS` package ? ...but according to docs I will not be able to use custom styles with this method.

I am a bit confused here , please help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SUI-React docs comment about not recommending use of Webpack 1 is simply because it's not the latest version of Webpack.  Webpack 1 still works fine in general.  Also, the current version of Create-React-App (1.0) uses Webpack 2, and if you haven't "ejected" your CRA project, you can easily upgrade the `react-scripts` dependency to use the latest version.

If you want to build a custom Semantic-UI CSS file, yes, you would install the `semantic-ui` package, and that will create a `semantic` folder containing Semantic-UI's LESS source files and build system.  From there, you would make any edits to SUI's source for your customization.  Once you've made your edits, run `gulp build` inside that `semantic` folder, and it will create a `semantic/dist` folder containing the compiled CSS files (per the instructions at https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html ).  Finally, you would copy the generated CSS files into your project, probably inside the `src` folder, and import those in your JS source.

If you don't care about generating a customized Semantic-UI CSS build, you can `npm install --save semantic-ui-css`, which has a pre-built version of the default Semantic-UI theme, and import the CSS from there.

For what it's worth, my own ["Practical Redux"](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/) tutorial series uses Semantic-UI-React and the `semantic-ui-css` package, and I show how to add `semantic-ui-css` in [Practical Redux, Part 4: UI Layout and Project Structure](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/11/practical-redux-part-4-ui-layout-and-project-structure/).  (I've also used a custom Semantic-UI CSS build in my "real" project at work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer and your "Practical Redux" tutorial is amazing too ! What is your feedback towards the performance of semantic-ui-react and semantic-ui ? I have read few posts where they mentioned about webpack build being too huge in size. Has it caused any trouble for you so far in terms of size?

Comment: To be honest, the particular app I'm working on is still in the prototype stages, and we haven't dealt with bundle size optimization yet.  I will say that both SUI and SUI-React do seem a bit large, so they're probably not the best choice if you're trying to create a highly optimized bundle, but they do provide a lot of functionality and a good basic appearance out of the box.

Comment: I am also in a very initial stage of my project, so probably I will look for some other option if size is an issue here..I really liked antd library but a part of their documentation is still untranslated. React bootstrap looks like an option as well . What do you think of React bootstrap and antd?

Comment: Haven't seriously looked at or investigated either of them.